# Why is my dishwasher leaking from the bottom despite tightening this connection?

Tags: plumbing, leak, appliances, dishwasher

I found I have leaking from the bottom of the dishwasher.

I tried to tight it but I could not and still leaking when it’s not running.[image]

Should I use thread seal tape here ?

Comment: You can tell that it is cross-threaded so it's not getting a good seal. You need to unscrew it completely and try again with it lined up properly and hope the plastic threads are not too damaged.

Comment: @DJ,  make that comment an answer...it IS the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good picture -- and clearly, that brass input hose connector is crooked, i.e., cross-threaded. Reinstall it so it's not at an angle. If that doesn't fix it, then a rubber washer inside might now need to be replaced, rather than adding tape dope.

[image: Cross-threaded]

Comment: Be _very_ cautious! The brass (while a soft metal) is significantly harder than the plastic fitting that it's attached to. That cross-threading might have damaged the plastic threads - if that's happened, no amount of tread tape, pipe dope and tightening will keep it from leaking. Be prepared to identify that part and purchase a replacement. Give the plastic threads a thorough inspection - if you see significant damage to them, you'd probably be better off just ordering a replacement up front.

Comment: @FreeMan, first, it looks like the fitting was not tightened much, since most threads are exposed, and are *intact*. Second, the plastic *is* soft, and the brass will act as a die, once it grabs onto the good threads, repairing some of the damage. It's fairly likely, if the coupling is put on correctly, it would be fine. That said, as you say, tape dope would not help, because the brass coupling is open at bottom.